# 'Authorization: Bearer Undefined'

Tags: node.js, angular, jwt, authorization, angular-http-interceptors

[image]

the Authorization header is always undefined when I am trying to login. Tried setting AOT = false in my angular.json file but to no avail. What is the issue here?

**Auth-Interceptor**

```js
import { HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";


@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor{
    constructor(private authService: AuthService){}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler){
        const authToken = this.authService.getToken();
        const authRequest = req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken)
        })
        return next.handle(authRequest)
    }   
}
```

**checkAuth middleware on backend**

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
        jwt.verify(token, "asderfghtyu")
        next();
    }
    catch(error) {
        res.status(401).json({
            message: "Authorization failed macha"
        })
    }
}
```

**auth-service.ts**

```
 export class AuthService {
  private token: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getToken(){
    return this.token;
  }
  
  createUser(FullName: string, email: string, role: string, password: string) {
    const authData: AuthData = { FullName: FullName, email: email, role: role, password: password }
    this.http.post("http://localhost:3300/api/user/signup", authData)
      .subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result);
      })
  }

  login(email: string, password: string){
    this.http.post<{token: string}>("http://localhost:3300/api/user/login", {email: email, password: password})
    .subscribe(response=>{
      const token = response.token;
      this.token = token;
    })
  }
```

Here is the auth-service.ts file where `getToken()` function is present

Comment: There is nothing wrong with how you are setting the header. What ever is getting returned from `this.authService.getToken();` is undefined.

Comment: I have edited my post with the auth-service code too. please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Auth-Interceptor`, replace -

```js
const authRequest = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken)
    })
```

with -

```js
const authRequest = !authToken ? req : req.clone({
        setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}` }
    });
```

This will add an `Authorization` header only if you have a token. If `authService.getToken()` returns `undefined`, no `Authorization` header will be added to the request.

Comment: Still the same. No changes. :(

Comment: @RP Then put `console.log(authToken);` after the line - `const authToken = this.authService.getToken();` and check if `authToken` has value.

Comment: It  prints undefined at first, but after I press the login button for the 2nd time it prints the token value

Comment: @RP That is the normal/expected behavior. When you first try to login, the request header will not have a token, because you have not logged in yet and the server haven't issued a token. Once the login is successful, the server issues you a token and any request after that should have a token in the header.

Comment: @RP Is that (what I mentioned in the previous comment) what's happening in your case? If so, then I will delete this answer, and vote to close the post. Or, may be you should delete the post.

Comment: So what will I have to do if I want the server to issue the token as soon as the user hits the login button, instead of showing undefined token at the first time?

Comment: @RP Are you receiving any error/exception for that `Bearer undefined`?

Comment: @RP Please try the updated code. It will add an `Authorization` header only if you have a token.